# jQuery swap div on hover with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create two "buttons" that using the hover event, hide some divs and then display some others in their place. I'm then trying to delay the swapping back to the default div.

All works, fine, unless you go from one button to the other at which point you get many divs displaying at the same time until the delay passes. If we don't use the delay it works perfectly.

The javascript:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$('#servers-btn').hover(
   function() {
    $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').show(0);
    $('#default, #default-heading').hide(0);
   }, 
   function() {
   setTimeout( function() {
        $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').hide(0);
        $('#default, #default-heading').show(0);
        },1000)
    }
);

$('#hosting-btn').hover(
   function() {
    $('#hosting, #hosting-heading, #hosting-arrow').show(0);
    $('#default, #default-heading').hide(0);
   }, 
   function() {
   setTimeout( function() {
        $('#hosting, #hosting-heading, #hosting-arrow').hide(0);
        $('#default, #default-heading').show(0);
        },1000)
    }
);

});
```

I assume i need to make one hover function aware of the other so it can cancel the timeout, i just have no clue how to do it.

EDIT - just tidyed up code to put all divs into one hide/show.

Also, i should have probably mentioned that the #default, #servers and #hosting divs appear in exactly the same location. So need to instantly switch at the same time (which the above does).

EDIT - latest attempt to use clearTimeout here http://jsfiddle.net/KH4tt/1/ - but can't quite make it work right.

Comment: please use this example, like this\ jQuery('#hosting').stop(true,true).show(0);

Comment: @ShibinRagh would i have to be using the delay() for this to work?

Comment: What if i use the clearTimeout function? Just not sure exactly how to implement it.

Comment: @ShibinRagh http://jsfiddle.net/KH4tt/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's the final thing using the clearTimeout() function to cancel the setTimeout() that is used on mouseleave (hover handlerOut) that creates the delay:

```
jQuery(function($) {

var timeoutserver;

function canceltimeout() {
if (timeoutserver) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutserver);
    timeoutserver = null;
}
}

function closeServertime() {
    timeoutserver = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').hide(0);
        $('#default, #default-heading').show(0);
    }, 1000);        
}

function closeHostingtime() {
    timeoutserver = window.setTimeout(function() {
        $('#hosting, #hosting-heading, #hosting-arrow').hide(0);
        $('#default, #default-heading').show(0);
    }, 1000);        
}


$('#servers-btn').hover(

function() {
    canceltimeout();
    $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow, ').show(0);
    $('#default, #default-heading, #hosting, #hosting-heading, #hosting-arrow').hide(0);
}, function() {
    closeServertime();
});

$('#hosting-btn').hover(

function() {
    canceltimeout();
    $('#hosting, #hosting-heading, #hosting-arrow').show(0);
    $('#default, #default-heading, #servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').hide(0);
}, function() {
    closeHostingtime();
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .delay() function in jquery (I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 version) like the below example:

```
$(selector).delay(1000).hide("slow");
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried using delay instead of the setTimeout but it causes the content to jump slightly, as the two events on mouse out don't seem to execute at exactly the same time. If i could wrap them both in one delay() that might work, but i don't know how? Also it still doesn't solve the key issue that if you hover over the other button within the delay() period, you get the old mouseleave happening _after_ the new mouseenter.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('#servers-btn').hover(
   function() {
    $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').show(0);
    $('#default, #default-heading').hide(1000, function() {
        $('#servers, #servers-heading, #servers-arrow').hide(0);
        $('#default, #default-heading').show(0);
    });
   }
);
```